# What are the punishments for evoking lust in another person?

Tags: scripture, sin, garuda-purana, punishment, lust

What are the punishments given to a man/woman (mostly woman) who creates lustful feelings to the opposite sex by showing skin / private parts and blabber.

Any references from scriptures like Garuda Purana or Bagawatham?

Comment: It is not important to seek religious texts to seek rules and information on ever-changing law, order, and culture. Culture and adaptation to a particular culture is not the goal of mainstream Hinduism, but rather an enlightenment, or liberation through continuous efforts of discipline, worship, practices, and sadhana for liberation.

Answer (score 0):

Relevance of Question:

I understand this question as "Punishments to person showing more glamour or inducement by various ways impacting other person".

It is a tough question because many cinema/film heroes/heroines & actors are desirous exhibitors of lust to public. STILL THERE IS AN ANSWER:

FRAGILITY & DEGRADING GENES OF NEXT GENERATION
Exceptions:
As such, this question is not applicable to a human family of husband & wife and

Hinduism in temple architecture of first entrance to temple depicts such glamour sculptures along with God deities: What it means

```
      THE WEAKER SOCIETY
```

Those who get attracted loose their spiritual power towards desires & attractions instead of spiritual powers towards God.

The driving force of human life lies on CHAKRAS inside body. But tempted to sexual desires humans loose CHAKRA energy in others except SVADISHTAANA. Thus loose balance in thinking.

example: Sage Vishwamitra(while king) lost his balance of CHAKRA.

THE DOER OF LUSTFUL ACTS TO IMPACT OTHERS - Such doers are created by
spirits for following

1. Recurrence share of cycles within janmas of others in DEMONAIC world
2. Yakshas(formless partly Divine partly Demon spirits) revenging those who had violated/ opposed/ shamed BRAHMATATVAM of BRAHMANAAS(priestly class) because the priests cannot be physically powerful. Yakshas do this because their liberation after many janmas depend on Priest's DEEKSHA.
3. Invasion of Aatma of other person by increasing dependability on desires thereby remotely controlling a person

PUNISHMENT IS INDIRECT/HIDDEN

Lust is banned in public in Hinduism because person who exhibits more lust as happiness is not punished by God but creates disturbance for females in society.

Krishna in Bhagavad Gita has delivered

"KAAMAM AASHRITYA DUSHPOORAM DAMBA MAANA MADA ANVITAAHA. MOHAAT GRUHEETVA ASATH GRAAHAAN PRAVARTHANTHEY ASUCHI VRATAHAA"

Those who understand lust as everything in life, they try to hoard wealth by unlawful acts, but still they are impure and try to follow rituals of unjustful acts leading towards destruction of their own genes(AsuchiVrataahaa does not denote bad fasting but the act to produce younger generation of kins goes degraded)".

CONCLUSION:

It is better to understand that KAAMA is desire but must be a private impact but MOKSHA is freedom that may have a mutual impact. Those entirely away from KAAMA were Saints in skies.